# Create a cleanup cd/floppy disc?

Tags: windows, boot, scripting, cleanup

I need to be able to do the following:

Boot from said disk
delete all C:\documents and settings\jafdkjewi folders (Excepting All Users, Default User, and Select Few others)
reboot

Help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Windows PE or Bart PE should be able to do this, but why are you not deleting profiles in the usual, documented and accepted manner?

[Google Link](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=xp+delete+user+profile&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=0&fp=99a1c4bc802b3f96) - 
[Windows Tip Of The Day Link](http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.com/2006/07/windows-xp-delete-user-profile.html) - 
[Microsoft Profile Delete Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=901a9b95-6063-4462-8150-360394e98e1e&displaylang=en)

Comment: Agreed - people always seem to want to just delete the folders instead of delete the profile... <sigh>

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say he isn't the admin and wants to cover his own tracks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just download a live CD of your favorite flavor of Linux.

Comment: Why would you when there's a documented way to delete profiles, unless the OP has more info that we don't know (e.g. can't do it)?  I'll take back my down vote if that's the case.

Comment: Why is irrelevant. Maybe he's a CIA spy who's gone rogue and is defecting? Actually you're right, it's very odd, but anyway, a live cd is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to do this in order to clean old computers off for re-use?

If so, I recommend you clean one and take an image of the hard drive, then deploy using that.
Assuming they are all the same model, this would be easy.

Otherwise mh has the best answer, but it will need some time for you to build it.